# QVTKWidget was deprecated for VTK 8.1 and will be removed in a future version

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, qvtkwidget

When i create a qt gui vtk application by Cmake,then i run it with vs 2017.It appears fllowing warning.Any counld tell me how could i cancel this warning?Thank you a lot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHrJL.png)

Answer (score 2):

You should use QVTKOpenGLWidget instead.

You can disable deprecation warning if absolutely needed by setting the cmake variable :

```
VTK_LEGACY_SILENT:ON
```